# Trying to get property of non-object? PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have been literally pulling my hair out with this one and its beginning to delay the rest of my project and it really is getting me down.

I am trying to populate a pull down using values taken from a database table so that if in the future the user wants to add more options to the pull down they can add them to the table in the database.

**I am using the Codeigniter platform (PHP) using MVC design pattern.**

Here is the error message I am getting:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object Filename: views/submit.php Line Number: 139

**My Model function is this here which retrieves the rows from the table called "Staff".
This works fine!**

```
function retrieve_values()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('staff');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    { 
        //true if there are rows in the table
        return $query->result_array(); //returns an object of data
    }

    return false;
}
```

**This is the controller function which receives the parameter and passes it to my view.
This works fine!**

```
public function displayform()
{

    //Checks if a user is logged in, if they are not they get redirected -
    if ( $this->session->userdata('name') == FALSE || $this->session->userdata('access_level') == FALSE)
    {
        redirect ('site/index');// to home page
    }

    //Stores the returned array in instance called "formdata" which will be passed to the view to be used in pulldown menu
    $page['formdata']=$this->submit_model->retrieve_values();

    //This loads the form 
    //Instance of "page" in array "page" specifies the file name of the page to load
    $page['page'] = 'submit';
    $this->load->view('template', $page );

    return;
}
```

This is the part of the view which is causing the problem: I am using a foreach and then echoing the instances of the array into the option.

```
<select>
    <?php foreach ($formdata as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->staff_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

`printr()` of the variable `$formdata` shows that it contains these values:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 1
        [name] => Cardiology Nurse
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 2
        [name] => Radiology Nurse
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 3
        [name] => Scrub Nurse
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 4
        [name] => Circulating Nurse
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 5
        [name] => Nurse
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 6
        [name] => Training Nurse
    )
    [6] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 7
        [name] => Physiologist
    )
    [7] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 8
        [name] => Radiographer
    )
    [8] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 9
        [name] => Consultant
    )
    [9] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 10
        [name] => Radiologist
    )
    [10] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 11
        [name] => Cardiologist
    )
    [11] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 12
        [name] => Anaethestist
    )
    [12] => Array (
        [staff_id] => 13
        [name] => Non-medical Staff
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you using includes/requires along with sessions to store objects? I believe that if you store an object in a session then you must include/require the file containing the object's class definition before you start the session.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

formdata is an array of arrays, not objects, so simply change in your view:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row->staff_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
// to
<option value="<?php echo $row['staff_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
```

Comment: THANKYOU THANKYOU THANKYOU! I Will be more careful of my retun results

Answer (score 3):

You've used [`result_array`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html), which means you're going to get an array of arrays, instead of an array of objects. You can either modify your view to have this:

```
<option value="<?php echo  $row['staff_id']; ?>">
    <?php echo  $row['name']; ?>
</option>
```

instead of

```
<option value="<?php echo $row->staff_id; ?>">
    <?php echo $row->name; ?>
</option>
```

or you can change `$query->result_array()` to `$query->result()` in the model.